# Cannot change configuration ':android:compile' after it has been resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've got a gradle project consisting of 3 build.gradle files in modules and one parent.

The parent has the following structure:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    }

}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        ...
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        ...
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        ...
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

I need to add the following dependency  *compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'* and i did it in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

as well as applied plugin at the beginning of android module file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

got this:

```
Error:Cannot change configuration ':android:compile' after it has been resolved.
```

When I move this dependency to :android section of main build file but it says:

```
Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
    file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
    https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
    http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.pom
    http://repo.spring.io/milestone/com/google/android/gms/play-services/8.4.0/play-services-8.4.0.jar
```

Should i somehow reorganize all the dependencies to corresponding build.gradles in modules or there is another way to make it work?